# Meteor access data context in onCreated

Tags: meteor

I have a list of tasks and I want to load a list of corresponding comments when I click one of the Tasks.
Iron router code:

```
Router.route('/taskComments/:_id', function () {
        var item = Tasks.findOne(this.params._id);
        this.render('commentList', {data: item});
    },
    {
        name: 'taskComments',
        fastRender: true
    }
);
```

Template helpers:

```
Template.commentList.helpers({
    comments: function(){
        return Comments.find({taskID: this._id});
    });
```

I am able to access the task id (this._id) in the above snippet, but it does not seem to work for onCreated:

```
Template.commentList.onCreated(function(){
    this.subscribe("comments",this._id);
});
```

When I console log this it gives me the following object:

[image]

Notice that there is no _id and data is also null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Template.currentData()` inside of this callback to access reactive data context of the template instance. The Computation is automatically stopped when the template is destroyed.

```
Template.commentList.onCreated(function(){
  var self = this;
  var dataContext = Template.currentData()
  self.subscribe("comments",dataContext._id);
});
```